# How can I embed the bot's reply? discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I made a "funnyrate" command that is working perfectly fine. However I think it would look better if the bot's reply is embedded. may someone help me make the bots reply embedded? here is the code:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
  var mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first();

  if (!mentionedMember) return message.reply(`according to my calculations, you are ${rating}% funny`);
  return message.channel.send(`${mentionedMember}, according to my calculations, you are ${rating}% funny`);
}

module.exports.help = {
name:"funnyrate"
}
```

Comment: Refer to [This Guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html) for constructing and sending embeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firstly if you don't know how to make embeds,you should visit: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTitlelink.
This is a link to the discord.js embed documentation page.

I haven't tried it but this should work:
Have a good day!

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
   
   var rating = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
 
   if (!args.length) {

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(`according to my calculations, you are ${rating}% funny`)
      
      return message.channel.send(embed);
   } else {

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setDescription(`${mentionedMember}, according to my calculations, you are ${rating}% funny`)
     
      return message.channel.send(embed);
   }}
 
 module.exports.help = {
 name:"funnyrate"
 }
```